# Integration of WebRTC from CodenameOne

Tags: webrtc, codenameone

Can anyone please shed some light on how to integrate webRTC from apps built with codenameOne. My client has already implemented WebRTC based video chat from their web application and wants to integrate same from Mobile app being built with CodenameOne.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native implementation of WebRTC in Codename One. However, you can use [BrowserComponent](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html) and possibly the [JavaScript bridge](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/javascript/JSObject.html) to implement it from Java.

I don't think that the JavaFX browser in the simulator supports WebRTC but this should generally work on devices though I haven't verified it.